# Postgres data loss

Tags: python, django, postgresql, heroku

We have an app hosted on Heroku. Recently, I witnessed data being lost from the postgres database. The app is made with django, and there are news articles. So I edited the title of an article and saved it. I could see that changes were saved in the django admin and on the site the corrected title appeared. But after a while, the old version of the title reappeared on the site. So I edited the title for the second time, and the same thing happened again. This time, it took sometime between 1 and 30 minutes for the old version to reappear.

I am completely confused to what might be happening here. There is no indication of any kind of error in the logs.

I asked Heroku support for assistance, but without being able to reproduce the error, they couldn't really do much.

This phenomenon happened twice. I'd like to understand it so if anyone has a theory, please share it.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you check what actually happens with the data on the database level? Does it change there?

Comment: When I opened the article at the website, the content was retrieved from the database, and changes were visible.

Comment: I'm asking you to check it up on Postgres without any third party in between.

Comment: Ok. I understand. But now it's impossible to check since I can't reproduce the error.

Comment: Do you have other admins? If you and admin #2 both brought up the same article and made changes, whoever makes the changes later will overwrite ... alternatively, if you're using some caching, that could cause similar behavior but I wouldn't expect that here.

Comment: No caching. We do have other admins, but none of them were editing this particular item.